# Reading Edid using i2c - "ioctl" versus "read"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, edid

Folks,

I am looking at various implementation of reading edid code.

In one implementation, I see the following:

```
 err = ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, 0x50);
 if (err == 0) {
     // ok to read.
     for(int i=0;i<128;i++) {
        buf[i] = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(fd); // use ioctl to read 1 byte at a time
     }
 }
```

In another implementation, I see:

```
 err = ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, 0x50);
 if (err == 0) {
     usleep(TIMEOUT); // sleep for a brief interval
     write(fd, &command, 1); // here, command[0] is 0
     usleep(TIMEOUT); // sleep for a brief interval
     read(fd, buf, 128);
 }
```

The first implementation is from http://www.polypux.org/projects/read-edid/ and the second one is from libXcm implementation.

I have used the first implementation. I am wondering if the second implementation is acceptable.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Did you figured this out?